Where to get advice on living in Poland and working PAYE in the UK
I recently moved to Poland and want to work for a UK company as a PAYE employee. The information from .gov tells me this should be possible and my UK accountant says the tax should be paid in the region I live.
What sort of company or advisory person should I be speaking to get the truth of this matter?
Is this even possible or should I be looking for contract work only?

AFAIK you pay PAYE if you are a UK tax resident, for example if you visit the UK for more than 183 days in a tax year. So your accountant is correct, if you are resident in Poland and spend most of your time there.

Thanks @Traveller. I got this link from my accountant. But I need to know the details of how to set this up, at least on the U.K. side. Any references?

I would presume that if you’re going to be working for a UK-based company that already has remote employee(s) in Poland, then the employer would assist you. If that’s not the case, you may find that you can only work as a contractor, because for the company the hassle of one employee in Poland isn’t worth the effort.

Right - this is what I'm trying to find out... What is that hassle and what does it involve?

The link your accountant gave you has a long-ish list of considerations/potential consequences for an employer, including eg payroll withholding obligations, and whether you’d be in scope of foreign labour law. The hassle for the employer would be figuring all that out and maintaining processes to ensure compliance. Not worth it for just one employee.
